# problema de URL no codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

Eu tenho uma aplicação em um servidor:

`http://192.168.0.200/aplicacao`

Quando faço autenticação para acessar aparece este erro:

> The requested URL /aplicacao/auth/login was not found on this server.

Pesquisei e vi que pode ser no arquivo `.htaccess`. Alterei ele mas continua igual:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /aplicacao/index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Ocorre o mesmo erro citado acima.

Quando eu tinha a aplicação no `localhost`, funcionava sem problemas e eu configurei os arquivos do `codeigniter` para url amigável.

Comment: Se você alterou a rota da sua URL verifique se quem está chamando essa sua autenticação está com a rota que setou em routes.php ou a URL normal.

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser o .htaccess mesmo e relacionado com a sobrescrita de URL do servidor. Para usar URL amigável (excluindo o index.php da URL) é preciso configurar o .htaccess da raiz do projeto da seguinte forma:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Em seguida é preciso verificar se a sobrescrita de URL está ativa no servidor. você deve ativar da seguinte forma:

1. Abra o arquivo httpd.conf do servidor web;
2. Descomente a linha `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` retirando o `#` do início da linha (ou outro caracter de comentário que existir);
3. Reinicie o servidor.